# How to solve this limit without using L'Hôspital?

Tags: calculus, limits

This limit *wildly* appeared in a test and, well, I could not solve it without using L'Hôspital rule - which were not allowed in the test. Can anyone help me?

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-1}$$

---

Answer, thanks to @user71352.
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-1}}{1}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}
$$
Multiply by the conjugate:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}})^2-(\sqrt{x-1})^2}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}
$$
Multiply by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}
$$
Knowing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 0$:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}}=\frac{0-1}{\sqrt{1-0}+\sqrt{1-0}}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Multiply by the "conjugate."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-1}=\frac{x-\sqrt{x}-x+1}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x-1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}}
$$

Comment: You're welcome.